# Error in list index python hand gesture recogniser opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am making a hand gesture recognizer, using OPENCV in PYTHON. I refereed to a YouTube tutorial, and it worked fine there, but i have encountered an error. I am a new coder.

here is my code:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while capture.isOpened():
    # while True:
    ret, img = capture.read()

    cv2.rectangle(img, (300, 300), (100, 100), (255, 255, 255), 2)
    crop_img = img[100:300, 100:300]

    grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    value = (35, 35)
    blurry = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayscale, value, 0)

    _, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(blurry, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    cv2.imshow('Threshold', thresh1)

    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh1.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cont = max(contours, key=lambda item: cv2.contourArea(item))

    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cont)
    cv2.rectangle(crop_img, (x, y), (w, h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    hull = cv2.convexHull(cont)

    drawing = np.zeros(crop_img.shape, np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, [cont], 0, (0, 255, 0), 0)
    cv2.drawContours(drawing, [hull], 0, (0, 0, 255), 0)

    hull = cv2.convexHull(cont, returnPoints=False)

    defects = cv2.convexityDefects(cont, hull)
    count_defects = 0
    cv2.drawContours(thresh1, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)

    start = ()
    end = ()
    far = ()

    for i in range(defects.shape[0]):
        s, e, d, f = defects[i, 0]

        start = tuple(cont[s][0])
        end = tuple(cont[e][0])
        far = tuple(cont[f][0])

        a = math.sqrt((end[0] - start[0])**2 + (end[1] - start[1])**2)
        b = math.sqrt((far[0] - start[0])**2 + (far[1] - start[1])**2)
        c = math.sqrt((end[0] - far[0])**2 + (end[1] - far[1])**2)

        angle = math.acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2)/(2*b*c)) * 57

        if angle <= 120:
            count_defects += 1
            cv2.circle(crop_img, far, 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    cv2.line(crop_img, start, end, (0, 255, 0), 2)

    if count_defects == 1:
        cv2.putText(img, '1 Finger', (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 2)
    elif count_defects == 2:
        cv2.putText(img, '2 Fingers', (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 2)
    elif count_defects == 3:
        cv2.putText(img, '3 Fingers', (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 2)
    elif count_defects == 4:
        cv2.putText(img, '4 Fingers', (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 2)
    elif count_defects == 5:
        cv2.putText(img, '5 Fingers', (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 2)
    else:
        cv2.putText(img, 'Unknown gesture', (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 2)

    cv2.imshow('Gesture', img)
    all_img = np.hstack((drawing, crop_img))
    cv2.imshow('Contours', all_img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
```

this shows an error while executing at line 50:

```
 line 50, in <module>
    far = tuple(cont[f][0])
IndexError: index 1635 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 596
```

I am making a hand gesture recogniser, and it works properly on my friend's python. Please help, thanks

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

I never use it but in some examples I see different order `s, e, f, d` instead of `s, e, d, f`

```
s, e, f, d = defects[i, 0]
```

and now your code works for me.